# Why make prints out the echo line?

Tags: makefile, echo

I am reading about Makefiles and trying to do some stuff with it. But I noticed that it prints the echo command with the message associated with it!! (See the output)

Here is my work:

```
all:    main

main:   f1.o f2.o main.o
        echo "Linking f1.o f2.o and main.o";
        $(CPP) -o $@ main.o f1.o f2.o

main.o: main.cpp
        echo "Compiling main.cpp";
        $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o $@

f1.o:   f1.cpp
        echo "Compiling f1.cpp";
        $(CPP) -c f1.cpp -o $@

f2.o:   f2.cpp
        echo "Compiling f2.cpp";
        $(CPP) -c f2.cpp -o $@
```

and here is the output:

```
[mih1406@mih1406-ArchLinux 4]$ make
echo "Compiling f1.cpp";
Compiling f1.cpp
g++ -c f1.cpp -o f1.o
echo "Compiling f2.cpp";
Compiling f2.cpp
g++ -c f2.cpp -o f2.o
echo "Compiling main.cpp";
Compiling main.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
echo "Linking f1.o f2.o and main.o";
Linking f1.o f2.o and main.o
g++ -o main main.o f1.o f2.o
```

Notice that it prints the two messages:

> echo "Compiling f1.cpp";
>
> Compiling f1.cpp

Comment: what happens if you only use `"Compiling f2.cpp"` without `echo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `make` echoes all the command it is about to launch. You can suppress that for one command by starting the corresponding line with `@`, e.g.

```
main:   f1.o f2.o main.o
    @echo "Linking f1.o f2.o and main.o";
    $(CPP) -o $@ main.o f1.o f2.o
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing for more information.